# JMeter: Starting new based on poisson timer

Tags: jmeter

Fairly new to JMeter and I have the requirement to start a new thread (Usercall) based on a poisson timer. I figured out how to create a poisson timer but not how to start a new thread based on a poisson timer. When I add the poisson timer in a dummy sampler at the start of the threadgroup it still executes the treads in parallel of course.

Goal would be to control the amount of threads by manipulating the poisson timer.

Edit:

So I would set the Poisson timer so that most calls will happen between 0 and 7 seconds. It would start a thread which would then execute a business case on the system. Next thread should be again started between 0 and 7 seconds and run in parallel with the first one. After the threads would run thru they close. This way it should not result in 1000 open threads and you can control the threads dynamically with the timer

Comment: Sure. So I would set the Poisson timer so that most calls will happen between 0 and 7 seconds. It would start a thread which would then execute a business case on the system. Next thread should be again started between 0 and 7 seconds and run in parallel with the first one. After the threads would run thru they close. This way it should not result in 1000 open threads and you can control the threads dynamically with the timer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a way to **start** threads with random delays I'm afraid that the only way is doing it using [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223). Take a look at [ThreadGroup.addNewThread() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/ThreadGroup.html#addNewThread-int-org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine-).

Example code:

```
ctx.getThreadGroup().addNewThread(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(0, 7), ctx.getEngine())
```

However I fail to see why just not to go for the [Poisson Random Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Poisson_Random_Timer), even if you start all the threads at the same time if you put the timer as a child of the 1st sampler the threads won't execute anything as the timer will add the delay.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. If I add the 1 sampler with Poisson timer it will start all threads more or less simultaneously as they are being executed parallel. What I want to do is start them in a synchronous manner and then let them run in parallel. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [ramp-up period](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-the-ultimate-guide) setting?